# Angular 5 + PrimeNG charts + spring boot + JHipster

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I have a problem with drawing charts using PrimeNG. But first things first, my main problem is I don't know how to convert data from rest API in Angular 5(TypeScript) and how to get the list of measurements from rest API. Of course, I have an endpoint which returns my list of measurements as JSON. 
I generate some sample charts to my app, for example line chart:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JhiLanguageService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import { Message } from 'primeng/components/common/api';

@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-linechart',
    templateUrl: './linechart.component.html',
    styles: []
})
export class LinechartComponent implements OnInit {
    data: any;
    msgs: Message[];

    constructor() {
        this.data = {
            labels: ['February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'First Dataset',
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Second Dataset',
                    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90],
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: '#565656'
                }
            ]
        };
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    selectData(event) {
        this.msgs = [];
        this.msgs.push({severity: 'info', summary: 'Data Selected', 'detail': this.data.datasets[event.element._datasetIndex].data[event.element._index]});
    }
}
```

This is simple line chart, so I add method which gets data from my rest endpoint. For PoC it looks like:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/measurements', {responseType: 'json'}).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

It displays jsons which look like:

```
{
    "batterStatus": 1,
    "humidity: 15": 15,
    "id": 1,
    "measurementTime": "2017-04-06T06:00:00+02:00",
    "temperatureInside" : 20,
    "temepratureOutside" : 30,
    "weight": 30
}
```

And here is my problem, I want to display on my chart lines for

- temperature inside
- temperature outside
- weight
- battery status
- humidity

per time measurement.

How to do that? To be honest, all my ideas were wrong.

Comment: Does your API only return one dataset or a list of them? Do you have only one dataset for each month or several?

Comment: API return list of them, I have 3 measurements per day

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a label for each measurement (e.g. row in your JSON response) and a dataset for each metric. I'm not familiar with PrimeNG, but as your metrics can't be displayed on one Y-axis, you might have to add an axis per metric.

I assume that it might also work with `datasets` being an object. If not, you need to convert it to an array. And if you want your app to work in Edge, unfortunately you can't use `Object.values` but have to loop through the values.

```
  /**
   * @type {Object} chart configuration. (You might want to create an Interface for that) 
   */
  chartData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: {
      temperatureInside: {
        label: 'Temperature inside',
        data: [],
        fill: false,
        borderColor: '#4bc0c0'
      },
      // repeat for each metric that you want in the chart
    }
  };

  /**
   * Build a chart configuration
   * @param {Array} data JSON response data
   */
  buildChartData(data: any[]): any {
    // validate data
    if (!data || data.length < 1) {
      return;
    }

    // loop through rows (measurements)
    for (const row of data) {
      // add the measurement to the X axis
      this.chartData.labels.push(row.measurementTime);
      // go through all metrics and store the value in the according dataset
      for (const key of Object.keys(this.chartData.datasets)) {
        // store the value in the dataset
        this.chartData.datasets[key].data.push(row[key]);
      }
    }

    // convert datasets into an array (it might acutally work without this)
    // NOTE: this is ES2017 and won't work in Edge
    this.chartData.datasets = Object.values(this.chartData.datasets);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ywxael?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Note: There is a typo in `temepratureOutside` that you might want to fix...